# Possible to have a dynamic Content-type in header for downloading files?

Tags: php, html

Is it possible to have PHP detect what the Content-type should be prior to downloading?  I'm fairly new to this but I was thinking of extracting the extension from the filename and then using a case statement to set the Content-type.

Is there a better way?

Comment: look into [finfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php) to get the mime type

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in downloading and not opening any particular application you can just use application/octet-stream.

Comment: For all files, and it is a common practice for downloads. Other content types are useful if you want the user to be prompted to open the file in an application.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Fileinfo extension: [php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php)

Comment: shamelessly stealing from comments

Comment: or maybe just an annoying, problematic, slow connection... you know :)